# How to hide Status Bar in Komodo Edit

Tags: statusbar, komodo, komodoedit

Hellow Im using Komodo Edit and want to hide status bar

Maybe where is some options to shell execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your userChrome.css file (You can find and/or create this file in your OS's default location for Komodo settings files, described [here](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations#appdata_dir). On OS X, for example, the Komodo Edit version of this file would be located at ~/Library/Application Support/KomodoEdit/8.0/XRE/chrome/userChrome.css).

```
#statusbarviewbox {
    display: none;
}
```

In addition, a somewhat complete guide to customizing the UI can be found on [this page](http://community.activestate.com/faq/customizing-the-komodo-ui), and a pretty nice macro that creates a "full screen" mode (absent of everything BUT the main edit window) can be found [here](http://community.activestate.com/node/6810).